# How do I get a coverage with external object in Apex Class?

Tags: unit-test, code-coverage, externalobjects

After retrieving data from an external object, I'm in progress type conversion to an External Object. However, when I run  test class, it is not covered from this point.

```
            test__x objT = new test__x();
            if(strObjectAPITemp !=null && strObjectAPITemp == 'test__x'){
                test__x objT = new test__x();
                String strKye; 
                for(SObject obj : listResult){
                    objT = (test__x) obj;
                    strKye = objT.Id;
                    if(objT.partid__r.Id == null) {
                        mapSaleItemTemp.put(strKye, objT); 
                    }
                }
            }
```

I'd like to know if there is a way to cover lines from this external declaration. Thank you so much.

Comment: Thank you for your kind recommendation!!